# Python user input (lists)

Tags: python

Hi again i was coding my text based game and came across another problem. My code:

```
print("\nPath 1 - bookkeeper", "\n Path 2 - mississippi", "\n Path 3 - sleeplessness", "\n Path 4 - keenness", "\n Path 5 - suddenness")
path_way = input("Scan the word you want by "
                 "\ntyping here to figure out the number associated  "
                 "\nwith each letter to add them up : ")
foreign_lang = []
occurences = []
for character in path_way:
    if character not in foreign_lang:
        foreign_lang.append(character)
        occurences.append(1)
    else:
        foreign_index = foreign_lang.index(character)
        occurences[foreign_index] = occurences[foreign_index] + 1

for index in range(len(foreign_lang)):
    print(foreign_lang[index], "-->", occurences[index])
print("Now that you added up you numbers use that number and")

while True:
  try:
    act_3 = int(input("Enter the number of henchmen you want to fight : "))
    if act_3==8:
     print("\n You easily fight the 8 henchmen and defeat them to proceed with the path!")

     break
    else:
        
     print("Sorry you have been killed as the henchmen overwhelmed you as there were too many of them")
  except:
    print("Sorry you have been kicked from the agency for quitting on the mission")
```

So I want to lead the user back to the list question instead of the while loop question if they enter the wrong answer in the while loop question. Does anyone know how I can do it?

https://trinket.io/python3/6f8defd82c

Comment: Please add sample input and output

Comment: Hi I linked the program to trinket for you to test it so I can lead the user to list question instead of the loop question. thks

Comment: you can simply create a function and add all the lines until `while True:` and call that function in `while True`.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand how you want me to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am comprehending your question correctly, then you can simply create a function and call it in your `while` loop.

```
def func():
    print("\nPath 1 - bookkeeper", "\n Path 2 - mississippi",
          "\n Path 3 - sleeplessness", "\n Path 4 - keenness",
          "\n Path 5 - suddenness")
    path_way = input("Scan the word you want by "
                     "\ntyping here to figure out the number associated  "
                     "\nwith each letter to add them up : ")

    foreign_lang = []
    occurences = []
    for character in path_way:
        if character not in foreign_lang:
            foreign_lang.append(character)
            occurences.append(1)
        else:
            foreign_index = foreign_lang.index(character)
            occurences[foreign_index] = occurences[foreign_index] + 1

    for index in range(len(foreign_lang)):
        print(foreign_lang[index], "-->", occurences[index])
    print("Now that you added up you numbers use that number and")


while True:
    func()
    try:
        act_3 = int(input("Enter the number of henchmen you want to fight : "))
        if act_3 == 8:
            print("\n You easily fight the 8 henchmen and defeat them to proceed with the path!")

            break
        else:

            print("Sorry you have been killed as the henchmen overwhelmed you as there were too many of them")
    except:
        print( "Sorry you have been kicked from the agency for quitting on the mission")
```

This will show your list of paths/questions until user enters correct option.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm doing a project and my class hasn't covered fucntions yet so I didnt know what you meant. But thanks again it works perfectly.

Comment: @Sainathi It would be better if you thanked people by accepting their answers if they have solved your problem. So far you've asked four questions, but have accepted none of them. All you need to do is click the outlne of an arrow next to the answer you want to accept.